# int** in c++ to objective c

Tags: c++, objective-c

what means the two stars in this c++ code, I try to convert it in objective c but I never saw that how can I do that?

```
int **gFFTBitTable = NULL;
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: Do you have a book, or have you searched the Web for a tutorial, to help you get started learning C++?

Comment: It means **exactly the same thing** in both C++ and Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

In both Objective C and C++ it is valid. It is pointer to pointer. As, pointer can keep address of other variable, pointer to pointer can keep address of pointer.

Example,

```
int i;

int *p = &i; //p is pointer 

int **q = &p; //q is pointer to pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

It means it's a pointer of pointers. If a pointer can be used like an array to keep track of say 10 integers (a row) a pointer of pointers could keep track of say 10 of those pointers (a table)